# Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSError' and 'NilLiteralConvertible'

Tags: swift, swift2

I have the following code :

```
if ((error) != nil) {
    print(error, terminator: "")
}
```

in my Swift program (converted to Swift 2 from Swift 1)

But Xcode is complaining

> Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSError' and 'NilLiteralConvertible'

What is the issue with the above line?

Comment: Your `error` is of type `NSError`.  It isn't an optional, so you can't compare it to `nil`.

Comment: If you let Xcode convert to the new syntax it probably surrounded your code with a `do try catch` block. If your code is inside the `catch` block error will never be `nil`.

Comment: Please show more code, including the declaration of `error`.

Comment: Since you can't compare it to nil and it's of type NSError, which doesn't compare to nil, should you just simply print the error without first checking if it has a value? If it's not an optional, that means that it must have a value correct? And what if there isn't an error? @vacawama

Comment: @DonAlejandro, more code needs to be shown to explain it further. I don't know how the error variable here was created, but the error message is clear that it is not an optional, so it can't be compared to nil.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try with following code and it works

```
if (error != []) 
{
    // do whatever u want
}
```

OR other option is to use try catch block available in swift 2.0

Comment: Can you explain this one? What is the right side of that comparison, an empty list?